# SearchView Issue

Tags: android, android-layout, searchview, android-search

**I am having android.support.v7.widget.SearchView in an xml but everytime i run my app , it showing me an error below . 
I am unable to figure out the issue .**

**Xml with searchview:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/contact_layout"
        android:background="@color/green_top_bar"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contact_headlineText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Contacts"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textSize="24dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />


        <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/searchview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

            app:iconifiedByDefault="false"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/contact_layout"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:padding="5dp"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**Gradle file:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:21'
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        preDexLibraries = false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.timemap"
        minSdkVersion 15
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:+'
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.1-beta1.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
    compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
}
```

**Activity.class(error occur while loading this)**

```
    public class Contacts_new extends ActivityGroup {
        @BindView(R.id.contact_headlineText)
        TextView title;
            @BindView(R.id.searchview)
            SearchView searchView;
        @BindView(R.id.recyclerview)
        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        @BindView(R.id.progress_bar)
        ProgressBar progressBar;


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact1);
            ButterKnife.bind(this);

        }
       }
}
```

Error :

```
                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.timemap/com.timemap.rendezvous.contacts.Contacts_new}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2201)
                                                                   at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
                                                                   at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
                                                                   at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:761)
                                                                   at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:425)
                                                                   at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:156)
                                                                   at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:741)
                                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4654)
                                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19438)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:366)
                                                                   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2031)
                                                                   at com.timemap.rendezvous.contacts.Contacts_new.onCreate(Contacts_new.java:43)
                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2201) 
                                                                   at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135) 
                                                                   at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347) 
                                                                   at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:761) 
                                                                   at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:425) 
                                                                   at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:156) 
                                                                   at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:741) 
                                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4654) 
                                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19438) 
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602) 
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702) 
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:366) 
                                                                   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2031) 
                                                                   at com.timemap.rendezvous.contacts.Contacts_new.onCreate(Contacts_new.java:43) 
                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451) 
                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2201) 
                                                                   at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135) 
                                                                   at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347) 
                                                                   at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:761) 
                                                                   at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:425) 
                                                                   at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:156) 
                                                                   at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:741) 
                                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4654) 
                                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19438) 
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602) 
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #97: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.java:289)
                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.java:275)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600) 
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702) 
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:366) 
                                                                   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2031) 
                                                                   at com.timemap.rendezvous.contacts.Contacts_new.onCreate(Contacts_new.java:43) 
                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451) 
                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2201) 
                                                                   at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135) 
                                                                   at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347) 
                                                                   at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:761) 
                                                                   at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:425) 
                                                                   at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:156) 
                                                                   at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:741) 
                                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4654) 
                                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19438) 
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602) 
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702) 
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.java:289) 
                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.java:275) 
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600) 
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702) 
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:366) 
                                                                   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2031) 
                                                                   at com.timemap.rendezvous.contacts.Contacts_new.onCreate(Contacts_new.java:43) 
                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451) 
                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2201) 
                                                                   at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135) 
                                                                   at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347) 
                                                                   at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:761) 
                                                                   at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:425) 
                                                                   at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:156) 
                                                                   at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:741) 
                                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4654) 
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602) 
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)               
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f0100e6 a=-1}
                                                                   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3394)
                                                                at an
```

Comment: add this in proguard file -keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }

Comment: @dumb_terminal : not working